# Is the accuracy calculated enough to make a valid assumption?

Tags: statistical-significance, accuracy

We did an experiment with colors. We compared the value of the CMY of the output color of our experiment against the reference value. We calculated the percent error for each of the color values, and then calculated its accuracy.

The percent error was calculated by getting the absolute value of the difference between each color value. The accuracy was calculated by getting the average of the three percent error values and then subtracting it from 1.

Keep in mind that the values are in percentages in decimal form.

The question is, is the value for the accuracy sufficient enough to create a valid assumption? For example, from the image below, can I safely conclude that there is no statistical difference between the output value and the reference value using the accuracy? Or is there another calculation to be done? If so, what are these tests?

[image]

Comment: I would say there is very little difference between reference and output values, of course these are only 3 examples.

Comment: yes, there are only three examples as they are meant for illustrative purposes only.

Comment: You probably know this, but colour is *incredibly* complicated, and perceived differences do not translate so easily into a simple mathematical framework ([there's always an xkcd, isn't there?](https://xkcd.com/1882/)). So I don't know that we can offer an informed opinion without knowing more about the data and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: How big an accuracy is big enough cannot be decided by the data. This is not really a statistical question. The color expert has to decide, potentially taking into account how exactly results will be used, how much accuracy is required. (After such a specification is made, statistics may come in to decide to what extent deviations from what is required could be explained by random variation, although I'm not even really sure you need that. Surely it's less important than the specification of how big is big enough.)